# NSDateFormatter does return what is expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, formatter

I created a method to return the NSDate from a NSString.  Code is below.  I send to the function "2/25/2011".  The function returns "2010-12-26 08:00:00 +0000"

What did I do wrong?  Also the NSString I need to release at the end.  How do I do that?

thank you!

```
-(NSDate *) GetDatefromString:(NSString *) Str
{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];

    NSDate *dateFromString;
            // = [[NSDate alloc] init]; tried taking this part out but still not working


    if (Str != NULL)
    {
        dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:Str];

    }
    else
    {
        dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:@"1/1/1970"];
    }

    [formatter release];

     return dateFromString;    

// how do I release dateFromString?

  /*  
    Printing description of dateFromString:
    2010-12-26 08:00:00 +0000
    Printing description of Str:
    02-25-2011
  */  
}
```

Comment: It's pretty clear you didn't even _try_ to read the docs, you're lucky anybody posted an answer.

Comment: It doesnt do any good to respond like this.  I read the docs upside down and backwards and then try everything I can think of. THEN finally I ask on here.  Your short sweet answer is a detriment to this forum IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was the format had CAP LETTERS for the YEAR.

This is correct:

```
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

And this is wrong: NOTE THE CAPS YYYY

```
[formatter
setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a date using the `/` seperator but you specified `-` as a separator for your date formatter. As to your question on releasing the string, you should only release objects that you own, i.e. that you have created with `new`, `alloc`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`. See examples below.

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // needs releasing
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

NSString* str1 = @"06/25/2011"; // does not need releasing
NSString* str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"06-25-2011"]; // needs releasing

NSDate* date1 =  [formatter dateFromString:str1]; // does not need releasing
NSDate* date2 =  [[NSDate alloc] init]; // needs releasing
date2 = [formatter dateFromString:str2]; 

NSLog(@"date from %@ : %@", str1, date1);
NSLog(@"date from %@ : %@", str2, date2);

// release the objects you own
[formatter release];
[str2 release];
[date2 release];

// prints out
date from 06/25/2011 : (null)
date from 06-25-2011 : 2011-06-25 00:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: I am not sure why you think I passed a date with /...  I passed in Printing description of Str: 02-25-2011.  But your explanation is fantastic.  I really appreciate you spending time to help with this!  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you set the format to`@"MM-dd-YYYY"`but the string you pass in has the form `@"1/1/1970"`. That doesn't match. see [Data Formatting Guide: Date formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

---

```
// how do I release dateFromString?
```

With [autorelease](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease).

```
return [dateFromString autorelease];
```

See [Memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Comment: I understood that is the return format not the sent format? Also I stated on the top of this I send 2-25-2011.  That seems correct to me?  What is wrong with that?

Comment: the formatter knows one format at a time. that it uses to create a nsdate. that doesnt link to a format. if you need another format later, you can have a second formatter with another format